# how to move uploaded file to a folder outside of the webroot?

Tags: php, upload, directory

Hi I want to create folders (with php) outside of the webroot and move uploaded files to them.
is that possible?how?

Comment: where ever you want , you can create folders and move files there, as long as you have permissions on the folders

Comment: [Read](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.move-uploaded-file.php) the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`rename`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php), [`copy`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) or [`move_uploaded_file`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php), though you need to make sure the folder has the correct permissions (write permissions for your webserver / php executing user).

Also, [Handling file uploads](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) might have some useful information for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use php's [move_uploaded_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) function.

Answer (score 1):

Linked in a comment, however it bears repeating: [Read](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.move-uploaded-file.php) the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php).

Check if the directory exists and if not, create it:

```
if (!is_dir('/dir/path')) {
    mkdir('/dir/path');
}
```

Move your uploaded file to the directory:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "/dir/path");
```